# Product color from select list in Commerce Kickstart 2

Tags: commerce

I thought it would be simple, but either I'm stupid or the commerce kickstart 2 doesn't have such functionality.

I've created a t-shirt product variation and I want to give my customers the possibility of choosing their favorite color from a color picker or from a select list. The color doesn’t affect the price.

As I see the only option for doing this in kickstart commerce is by creating each variation per color.
Is there any other way to accomplish this? I just want to create t-shirt and let people choose their color.

Please help me I'm getting very frustrated.

Comment: do you want  something like this? http://www.rikuni.com/blog/how-set-basic-drupal-commerce-store-product-options

Comment: I'm using kickstart commerce 2. Sorry @cayerdis, but article you provided, does not refer to KC2.

Comment: I solved it. I had to create my own module, the "Color Palette" module.
Example:
http://haftmarket.pl/pl/odziez/fartuch-kelnerski-d%C5%82ugi-gala

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what variations are for...

You have a product (a t-shirt) with a variety of different options (colours), hence you need different variations of the product to identify what colour of t-shirt has actually been sold.

Kickstart already has that exact functionality built right in; if you install the demo content and browse to "/tops/guy-short-sleeve-tee" you should see it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply but,
in my case I have t-shirts in about 100-150 different colors in the same price...

Comment: You need to add one product display per t-shirt style, with the associated colour variations referenced as individual products. If there's really 100-150 different colours of the same style of t-shirt, then you need to add and reference 100-150 products, e.g using commerce_bpc